# preg_replace a hashtag that doesn't end with ;

Tags: php, regex

I am currently using `preg_replace` to replace hashtags mentioned with html links like shown below. The issue is there is a possibility there will be html code as well being checked. So some css such as `color: #000000;` will force it to try convert that hex code into a link.

I basically need my regex to ignore doing any preg_replace if the last letter of a word is `;`. Here's what I currently have:

```
$str = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9!_%]+)/', '<a href="http://example.com/tags/$1">#$1</a>', $str);
```

Example input: `'I like #action movies!'`
Expected output: `I like <a href="http://example.com/tags/action">#action</a> movies!'`

I cannot use the end of the string to check this as chunks of text is checked at any given time so the string supplied could be `#computer text text text #computer` for instance.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Can you give an example here explaining what is your input string and what is expected output...?

Comment: I have edited my post with an example. The link formatting is correct and as expected, I just need to adjust my regex so it ignores words with ; on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you can check if next to your hashtag there is a ;, non alphanumeric, end of line or end of string:

```
/#([a-zA-Z0-9!_%]+)([^;\w]{1}|$)/
```

Then use $1 and $2 accordingly

```
'<a href="http://example.com/tags/$1">#$1</a>$2'
```

Your code will look like

```
$str = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9!_%]+)([^;\w]{1}|$)/', '<a href="http://example.com/tags/$1">#$1</a>$2',$str);
```

Here you can see some tests: https://regex101.com/r/yN4tJ6/65

Answer (score 1):

Until a regEx guru come to your rescue (if ever...) and because you are in PHP; here is a solution with few lines of code.

```
$str="hi #def; #abc #ghi"; // just a test case (first one need be skipped)

if (preg_match_all('/#([a-zA-Z0-9!_%]+.?)/', $str,$m)){
   foreach($m[1] as $k) if(substr($k,-1)!=';') {
      $k=trim($k);
      $str=str_replace("#$k","<a href='http://wxample.com/tags/$k'>#$k</a>",$str);
    }
}

print "$str\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition to check last string is ; or not and use it accordingly .
Example :

```
if (substr($str, -1)==';'){
//do nothing 
}
else {
$str = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9!_%]+)/', '<a href="http://example.com/tags/$1">#$1</a>', $str);
}
```

Hope this help .

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use below code, Actually I am new to regex so it is not that professional but it works, here it is

```
$data = "<p style='color:#00000;'>Heloo</p> #computer text text text #computer #say #goo1d #sd! #say_hello";
echo preg_replace("/(?<!\:)(\s+)\#([\w]+)(?!\;)/",'<a href="http://example.com/tags/$2">#$2</a>',$data);
```

This expression I have use

```
/(?<!\:)(\s+)\#([\w]+)(?!\;)/
```

Output is

```
<p style='color:#00000;'>Heloo</p> <a href="http://example.com/tags/computer">#computer</a> text text text <a href="http://example.com/tags/computer">#computer</a> <a href="http://example.com/tags/say">#say</a> <a href="http://example.com/tags/goo1d">#goo1d</a> <a href="http://example.com/tags/sd">#sd</a>! <a href="http://example.com/tags/say_hello">#say_hello</a>
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
#([\w!%]+(?=[\s,!?.\n]|$))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/KrRiD3/2

Your PHP code:

```
$str = 'I like #strategy games #f1f1f1; #e2e2e2; #action games!';
$str = preg_replace('/#([\w!%]+(?=[\s,!?.\n]|$))/', '<a href="http://example.com/tags/$1">#$1</a>', $str);
echo $str;
```

output:

> I like [#strategy](http://example.com/tags/strategy) games #f1f1f1; #e2e2e2; [#action](http://example.com/tags/action) games!

Comment: This wont match if the hashtag is at the end of the string

Comment: @phobia82 thanks for the catch :) I updated my code.